# What am I missing? I tried moving videos from Ubuntu 20.04 to IPhone 12

Tags: iphone

I just recently installed ubuntu 20.04 on a thinkpad p50. I also did the libmobile install. My computer does recognize my IPhone. I can see both the Photos and the documents folders. I can view the files but I’m unable to do any modifications to the files on the iPhone. When I try to delete files I get a message “you don’t have enough permission to delete this file”. When I trying to copy a file either from or to the iPhone. I get a message saying connection has been lost. I’m confused as it’s connected thru usb. I’m using the GUI as this is my first time trying out Ubuntu.  Thanks

Comment: I also tried moving and deleting files from a usb thumb drive and got an error message saying that I dont have permission. I feel like something is wrong with my account privileges. I do have an SSD as a second drive and I don’t have any issues moving or modifying files on that. Just seams like it’s with anything I connect via usb.